# how to start tomcat with http2.0

Tags: java, tomcat

When I configure http2.0 in server.xml. it make a error message :

> Failed to initialize connector
>   [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:105)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol
>   [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native
>   library which is not available    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:929)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:105)
>     ... 12 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check and make sure that port 8080 is not running (before starting tomcat)
and for more information about your problem please upload all your log file

do you get this error after update tomcat ?
if your answer is yes, this error is a bug :

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=888934

Comment: i just clear annotation about http2.0 in  server.xml not update . Should I use OpenSSL?

Comment: are you add "keystoreFile" in your https connection conf file ?